# How do you use apache to route different subdomains to different ports / servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, virtualhost

On my dev machine, I want to be able to have an SSL server, and a non-SSL server (both running off the same code... but running both servers is the easy part.)

For my regular server: I want it to be sub1.mydomain.com

so, I've modified my VirtualHost such that instead of saying

```
mydomain.com
*.mydomain.com,
```

it says

```
sub1.mydomain.com
*.sub1.mydomain.com
```

and then for the SSL server, I just said

```
sub2.mydomain.com
*.sub2.mydomain.com
```

except, whenever I got to a sub2.mydomain url, the server attached to sub1 processes the request.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using ruby on rails, and apache.

EDIT: added the actual virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/projects/myproject/public"
    ServerName reg.mydomain.com
    #ServerAlias *.reg.mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
    CacheDisable *
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/projects/myproject/public"
    ServerName ssl.mydomain.com
    #ServerAlias *.ssl.mydomain.com
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/certs/server.key"
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/certs/server.crt"

    ProxyPass / https://localhost:3002/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3002
    ProxyPreserveHost on    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do named virtual hosts?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Assuming that rails isn't doing anything too funky, you can try having a virtual host that looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName sub1.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1 or point this to the server instead.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName sub2.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sub2 or point this to the server instead.
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: so, I just can't have nested subdomains?

Comment: I've added my virtual hosts. Maybe I'm just not understanding the difference =\

Comment: The second virtual host is only on port 443 no? So any basic http requests will only go to the first virtual host? Is the current behavior that a request to http reg.mydomain.com and http ssl.mydomain.com both go to reg.mydomain.com? Does https ssl.mydomain.com and https reg.mydomain.com both go to ssl.mydomain.com?

Comment: that's right. everything goes to the server at reg.mydomain.com. =\

Comment: Try swapping the :443 for an :80. You can bind them both to port 80. You should go to the correct server then. You can probably remove the port number entirely from the second virtual hosts if you want it to process both https and http connections.

Comment: ok, so if they are both on port 80, ssl goes to the SSL server. But SSL is over port 443, so naturally it errors.

Comment: but, if I remove the port entirely, it goes to reg.mydomain... O_O

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. Can you add NameVirtualHost * to the very top?

Comment: ok, it used to say NameVirtualHost 80, but now it's a *. However, https://ssl.mydomain.com gets handeled by the reg.mydomain rails sever =( 

and then errors, cause it can't handle ssl =p

Comment: also, when I type in that https: url, i get this: proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost) in the console apache error_log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7293/discussion-between-nick-martin-and-thelindyhop)