# Is there a way to Serve vscode on web on a subpath

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode `code` command supports `serve-web` option which can start a vscode web server on any host and port, which can now accessed from browser.

```
% code serve-web --without-connection-token

* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to`
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
Web UI available at http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Is there a way to serve this vscode instance from a subpath(http://127.0.0.1/ide) instead of the root (http://127.0.0.1:8000) ?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR:

Generally speaking, if you want a service which is on one port to appear on another or in a different subfolder or subdomain you need to use a fronting web-server (specifically the 'reverse proxying' features thereof). Take a look at answers to similar questions but broaden your search beyond just VSCode's command line `code serve-web`.

#### Rationale:

There is command line help for vscode, which can be useful in understanding the tool's build-in limitations. You can get this via `code serve-web --help`, which returns the following results:

```
Runs a local web version of Visual Studio Code

Usage: code-tunnel serve-web [OPTIONS]

Options:
      --host <HOST>
          Host to listen on, defaults to 'localhost'
      --socket-path <SOCKET_PATH>
          
      --port <PORT>
          Port to listen on. If 0 is passed a random free port is picked [default: 8000]
      --connection-token <CONNECTION_TOKEN>
          A secret that must be included with all requests
      --without-connection-token
          Run without a connection token. Only use this if the connection is secured by other means
      --accept-server-license-terms
          If set, the user accepts the server license terms and the server will be started without a user prompt
      --server-data-dir <SERVER_DATA_DIR>
          Specifies the directory that server data is kept in
      --user-data-dir <USER_DATA_DIR>
          Specifies the directory that user data is kept in. Can be used to open multiple distinct instances of Code
      --extensions-dir <EXTENSIONS_DIR>
          Set the root path for extensions
  -h, --help
          Print help
```

Since there is no mention of the functionality you seek in the documentation (at the time of writing this answer), the next best solution could be one of the following:

- Compose the features you seek. Find another tool which you can combine with VSCode to achieve your objective, for example a suitable module on a web-server like Nginx or Apache HTTPD. Depending on how robust the solution needs to be, this might be suitable for your needs - for instance, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119004/how-do-you-use-apache-to-route-different-subdomains-to-different-ports-servers).
- Add the features you seek. Fork the VSCode source code and add the feature you need, as other open-source projects have done (again depends on your needs)
- Consider an alternative approach altogether for achieving your objective, contingent on your circumstances.